# Stuck in BusyBox initramfs

Tags: initramfs, busybox

Hello today i installed ubuntu and I couldn't connect to the internet nor did I have the wifi option in the settings.
Then I restarted and went to windows and saw that I had as much limber space as I had before installing ubuntu.
Then I restarted and I wanted to enter linux again and I got in BusyBox

Answer (score 0):

**To fix this error type:** 
fsck -f /dev/sda2 - sda2 is a partition type. 
Press yes the fix all errors. 
Then type reboot and the error is gone.
Please let me know if it worked. 
Thanks Jonathan.

Comment: i did someting like this and now i have another problem and i cant even type

Comment: Im still in busybox but i cant type

Comment: @Mihai Try to reconnect the keyboard. Then try to use another USB port or get another keyboard. Did you try to reset the PC? It works for me when I get this error.

Comment: I would do a hard reboot and then see if the error is gone as you said you did something similar and your keyboard stopped working.

Comment: Hello i fixed that problemem i reinstalled but now i cant connect to wireless network it works with Ethernet cablu but without i cant connect i dont even have wifi in settings and icon not showing